# Find after pattern plus next line

Tags: regex, find, sublimetext

In a HTML file with some PHP included

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>td1</td>
            <td>td2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <?php echo 'something' ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo echo 'something' ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo 'something' ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like to find all `<?php` that comes after `<td ...>` + *next line*.

(Here not `td1` and not `td2`)

Approach:

`(?s)(<td.*?>)+(\n)`... also matches `<td>td1</td>` and `<td>td2</td>`

What comes after `(?s)(<td.*?>)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `<?php...?>` you can replace `(<td[^>]*>)\s*<\?php.*?\?>` by `$1`:

[image]

Explaining:

```
(<td[^>]*>)              # store in $1 what you want to retrieve
\s*                      # also match what you want to remove
<\?php.*?\?>             # the php content
```

Then when replacing by `$1` it will remove only `\s*<\?php.*?\?>` which depended on `<td>`

Hope it helps.